# How to Manipulate Angular Attribute Directives to Respond to the Application Behavior

Tags: angular, angular-directive

Recently I came across a situation something like I should have to display and hide the DOM elements based on the state of the application. Let say that state of the application is **Admin view** and **employee view**. I have created a dropdown to toggle the view of the application.

```
<option (click)="enableAdminView()">Admin View <option/>
 <option (click)="enableEmployeeView()">Employee View <option/>
```

Upon clicking on the dropdwon I have registered an event to the RXjs Subject then my custom directive can subscribe to those events. Based on the event I need to display and hide the Dom elements.

**Custome Directive.ts**

```
  @Directive({
      selector: '[myApplicationView]'
    })
    export class ApplicationViewDirective {
       this.applicationView = 'Employee' ;
       constructor(private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
        private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef) {
              //Subscribe to ApplicationViewService
        ApplicationViewService.APPLICATION_VIEW_SUBJECT.subscribe((view) => {

          this.applicationView = view; // view can be Admin or Employee
          this.renderDomElements(view)
        });
        }

        @Input() set myApplicationView(view: string) {
          this.renderDomElements(view);
        }

    renderDomElements(view: any) {
      if(view === 'Employee'){
        this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
    } else if (view == Admin) {
     this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
    }else{
      this.viewContainer.clear();
    }

}
}
```

**HTML Nav Menu code snippet**

```
<div   *myApplicationView="'Admin'"> 
   ... // display admin related actions
  </div>

  <div   *myApplicationView="'Employee'"> 
   ... // display employee related actions
  </div>
```

The issue here was I can not access the host directive's @input value when calling **this.renderDomElements(view)** function inside the directive's subscriber function. I try calling **this.templateRef.elementRef.nativeElement** to get the host directive value but it is commented so can not access the directive Input value.So is there any way to access directive's Input value after it is initialized?

Comment: Any reason not to simply use `*ngIf` in the template?

Comment: Which input property are you referring to?

Comment: @WillAlexander yes the DOM manipulation is not applicable to only nav menu it could be an anywhere in the application. If I go *Ngif directive approach I have to repeat boilerplate codes for each component to mitigate that I switched into directive approach.

Comment: @Fredrik_Macrobond I used  `@Input() set myApplicationView` within the element we can pass values something like `*myApplicationView="'Employee'"`

Comment: There's not really much boilerplate. You can simply have a globally available BehaviorSubject which you consume as an Observable, using the `async` pipe in your `*ngIf` call. It seems far simpler than trying to directly manipulate the DOM (somewhat of an anti-pattern).